# Security of MSS

Tags: authentication, post-quantum-cryptography

I have started reading about the Merkle Signature Scheme. I am a little confused about why it is believed to be secure against quantum attacks, couldn't the hash function be attacked? What would make hash functions immune to quantum attacks? In addition doesn't the security also depend on the randomness of the private key used in the OT-signature algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a little confused about why it is believed to be secure against quantum attacks, couldn't the hash function be attacked?

Yes, the attacker could attack the hash function, for example, by trying to find a second preimage (and there are known Merkle Signature Schemes where we can show that forging a signature can be reduced to the second preimage problem).  However, the best known attack against a generic hash function is Grover's algorithm, which is able to find a second preimage for an $n$-bit hash function in $O(2^{n/2})$ time.  Hence, if we pick a 256 bit hash function, we make the expected effort to be $O(2^{128})$, which we believe is infeasible.

> In addition doesn't the security also depend on the randomness of the private key used in the OT-signature algorithm?

Yes, this is true.  Like almost all cryptography, the Merkle scheme assumes a secret that the attacker cannot guess.  Why is this a concern?  A Quantum Computer is of no more help in guessing this secret as it is in forming second preimages (assuming that the system was designed properly, of course)

Comment: Is Grover's algorithm also the best known attack against today's hash functions? What qualifies as a "generic hash function"? In addition, quantum computer's don't produce better attacks on PRNG's?

Comment: @dylan7: yes, Grover's algorithm is the best known against today's hash function (say, SHA-256).  What it does is, given a function with $m$ possible inputs, find the input where the function returns "yes" in $O(\sqrt{m})$ time (and when you use it to find a hash preimage, you make the function one that computes the hash, and then compare the result to the desired value).  As for PRNGs, there is no known attack against most PRNGs better than what's implied by Grover's algorithm.